# SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate running twice?

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

In my database handler class (extends SQLiteOpenHelper) I have the `onCreate()` Method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TASKS); 
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CONTACTS);
}
```

Sometimes (very rarely, but still) this leads to a crash because apparently the first table already exists. Obviously I can (and did) add `IF NOT EXISTS` to the statement to fix this, but what I want to know is what are the circumstances where `onCreate()` would be run if the table already exists. That is ordinarily not supposed to happen, so I've probably messed something up, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: I've been working with `SQLiteOpenHelper` for like 3 years now and I've never seen this error...

Comment: I also occasionally get some SQLiteDatabaseLockedExceptions because I have a bunch of database handler class instances doing stuff, sometimes simultaneously. Could this be causing the error? If so, then when I fix the database locked issue, this could go away as well.

Comment: Oh if you have other threads doing stuff on the DB then yes, it is normal. Another thread already created this table. I suggest you to not spawn other threads until the DB is created.

Comment: Yes, other threads are doing stuff at the same time. Could this issue be fixed by using the singleton pattern for the database handler class?

Comment: If you create a table at location that is not uninstalled with the app for example you create a table at /sdcard/myapp/data then reinstall the app this could happen.  Anyways Create if not exists is a best practice for DB.  You might just be repairing a corrupt installation get used to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to know is what are the circumstances where `onCreate()` would be run if the table already exists

Race condition: More than one thread trying to get a hold of the database via `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWritableDatabase()`.

Specifically if the threads are interleaved between `getVersion()` and `setVersion()` in the [code](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java#242):

```
242            final int version = db.getVersion();
243            if (version != mNewVersion) {
...
251                    if (version == 0) {
252                        onCreate(db);
253                    } else {
254                        if (version > mNewVersion) {
255                            onDowngrade(db, version, mNewVersion);
256                        } else {
257                            onUpgrade(db, version, mNewVersion);
258                        }
259                    }
260                    db.setVersion(mNewVersion);
```

There's a non-trivial amount of processing and some disk I/O involved so it's not hard for two threads to end up in this race.

Possible solutions:

- Synchronization: Use Java synchronization primitives to prevent the other thread from attempting to create the database at the same time.
- Singleton with synchronization. Ensure there's only one database helper.
- Access the database only in a single thread.

Comment: How could two threads be interleaved between `getVersion()` and `setVersion()`? That code block is part of private method `getDatabaseLocked()`, which is only called from synchronized code.

Comment: @Matt The synchronization is on the helper instance. If you have two instances of the helper, it doesn't help.

Comment: Ok, misunderstood your answer. That's why you're proposing a singleton as one of the possible solutions.

Comment: Also, to everybody who thinks they are already using `SQLiteOpenHelper` as a singleton: Check if any of your declared Android components uses `android:process=...`, as this will lead to `Application.onCreate()` being called a second time. I was initiating the migration logic from there. Don't forget to check all of your dependencies. ACRA 4.8.1 for example starts a service in a separate process.